# Inserting with Dapper.Contrib and DynamicParameters

Tags: c#, wpf, dapper

**QUESTION :**

**Is there a clever way to dynamically add parameters to an object and insert them in to a SQL DB?**

preferably using Dapper

---

I'm writing a WPF app where (amongest other things) I'm collecting questionnaire data. I'm using Dapper to map c# objects to SQL statements.

My problem is that I don't want to hard code all of the column names as object properties since I have a lot of them!

So I wanted to use Dapper's `DynamicParameters` to dynamically generate objects that Dapper can insert into the database by using the Dapper.Contrib `Insert` method.

I made an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class IDbRecord : DynamicParameters
    {
        [Key]
        public string H4Id { get; set; }
    }
```

and added parameters in another method using the `DynamicParameters.Add` method.

When my parameters have been added to my `IDbRecord` derived object I try to insert it.

This results is the `Insert` medthod trying to insert the public properties of `DynamicParameters` and not the content of the private `parameters` Dictonary. Which makes sense when looking at the Readme of Dapper.Contrib. I was just hoping that they had implemented `Insert()` to grab the `parameters` Dictonary when the object was derived from `DynamicParameters`.

Comment: did you tried using `Dapper.Contrib` or `Dapper.Rainbow` ?

Comment: @Kiquenet, Take a look a the title ;) 
I was trying to do this with `Dapper.Contrib`. I found a work-around. Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

I enden up iterating through my objects and building a SQL INSERT statement with a `StringBuilder`. Not very elegant. But it works

```
if (!hasData)
{
   var parameterList = new StringBuilder(null);
   var valuesList = new StringBuilder(null);
   var insertSql = new StringBuilder(null);
   parameterList.AppendFormat("Id, ");
   valuesList.Append(Id + ", ");
   foreach (var questionBase in answerList)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(questionBase.VariableName))
       {
           throw new ArgumentException("Question " + questionBase.QuestionNumber +
                                       " does not have a VariableName");
       }
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(questionBase.VariableName) && questionBase.Answer != null)
       {
           // insert keys (variable names)
           parameterList.AppendFormat("{0}", questionBase.VariableName);

           if (questionBase.QuestionNumber != answerList.Last().QuestionNumber)
           {
               parameterList.Append(", ");
           }

           // insert values
           valuesList.AppendFormat("{0}", questionBase.Answer);
           if (questionBase.VariableName != answerList.Last().VariableName)
               valuesList.Append(", ");
       }
   }

   try
   {
       insertSql.AppendFormat("INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2})", tableName, parameterList, valuesList);
       Connect(ConnectionHelper.DevConnString,
           c => c.Execute(insertSql.ToString()));
       return true;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       return false;
   }

}
```